# Tensorflow, node which is dead

Tags: tensorflow

I'm studying tensorflow process, however there are lots of hardness to understand the process.

1. One of term that I not fully understand is about node. In source code(C++ core), there are lots of various type of node. However I'm curious about dead node. It would be different from constant node. I want to know the reason of dead node existence, in other words, role of dead node.
2. What is live data vs dead data? Is that like data which is not used vs already used? ... I think I'm still not fully understand about this term. It can be shown in function ActivateNodes() (executor.cc)

I think these questions could be so basic for studying tensorflow, however I want to know exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dead tensors are an implementation detail of TensorFlow's control flow constructs: [`tf.cond()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) and [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). These constructs enable TensorFlow to determine whether or not to execute a subgraph based on a data-dependent value.

Let's consider the simpler `tf.cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn)` case. The value of `pred` determines whether the ops in `true_fn` or `false_fn` will be executed. In the current implementation, `pred` feeds into a [`Switch` op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/84e00bf64d89b8b39fe3b82fa305ee13b2a5613b/tensorflow/core/ops/control_flow_ops.cc#L44), which sends a regular tensor on one input and a dead tensor on the other input. If `pred` is true, the dead tensor is sent along `output_false` (and vice versa) The `tf.cond()` implementation is set up so that the ops in `true_fn` depend on the `output_true` and the ops in the `false_fn` depend on `output_false`.

When a tensor receives a dead tensor as one of its input, it doesn't execute; instead it sends a dead tensor on all of its outputs. This dead-tensor propagation ensures that only the ops in the appropriate branch will execute.

How does `tf.cond()` stop a dead tensor from propagating all the way to the output? A second special op, called a [`Merge` op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/84e00bf64d89b8b39fe3b82fa305ee13b2a5613b/tensorflow/core/ops/control_flow_ops.cc#L150) handles dead inputs differently. A `Merge` op has two or more inputs, and it expects to get a dead input for *all except one* of the inputs; it then forwards the not-dead input to its output. `tf.cond()` uses `Merge` ops to combine the results from the `true_fn` and `false_fn`, and so the results of the taken branch are returned as the output of the overall `tf.cond()` subgraph.

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I was not fully understand your answers. 
Can I ask one thing? 
As I understand, in tf.cond(), Switch op and Merge op are used for applying appropriate result according to pred.
However I'm not sure about dead-tensor propagation. If Merge op doesn't exist, tensor which has received dead tensor as input, the tensor will send to all outputs dead-tensor, right? In this point, why they send dead tensor to output? Is there any way for just removing the dead-tensor?

Comment: I realize something for question what I ask. I think removing is impossible because we don't know what state would be changed next iteration, so we can't manage the dead-tensor manually. Also sending process would be necessary when dead-tensor output has another process. Am I in the right track?

Comment: Right, the `Merge` op is the only supported mechanism that can "remove" a dead tensor. When there are multiple processes, dead tensors can be sent between them using the standard `Send` and `Recv` ops.