# Building custom keras layer, I encount InvalidArgumentError: Input 'pred' passed float expected bool while building

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I encounter a strange error during building a custom keras layer.
I'm trying to build a custom layer which is very similar with GRU layer but takes additional input in addition to sampled_z, in order to do teacher forcing in variational autoencoder.

I successfully build VAE model as following where terminal_GRU means the custom GRU layer.

```
Model: "VAE"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
encoder_input (InputLayer)      (None, 80, 69)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 80, 9)        5598        encoder_input[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 80, 9)        738         conv1d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)               (None, 80, 10)       910         conv1d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 800)          0           conv1d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 180)          144180      flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_mean (Dense)                  (None, 180)          32580       dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_log_var (Dense)               (None, 180)          32580       dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_sampling (Lambda)             (None, 180)          0           z_mean[0][0]                     
                                                                 z_log_var[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder (Model)                 (None, 80, 69)       1760451     z_sampling[0][0]                 
                                                                 encoder_input[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,977,037
Trainable params: 1,977,037
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

and decoder model looks like

```
Model: "decoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
encoded_input (InputLayer)      (None, 180)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reapeat_context (RepeatVector)  (None, 80, 180)      0           encoded_input[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder_GRU1 (GRU)              [(None, 80, 400), (N 697200      reapeat_context[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder_GRU2 (GRU)              [(None, 80, 400), (N 961200      decoder_GRU1[0][0]               
                                                                 decoder_GRU1[0][1]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
true_seq_input (InputLayer)     (None, 80, 69)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
terminal_GRU (TGRU)             [(None, 80, 69), (No 102051      decoder_GRU2[0][0]               
                                                                 true_seq_input[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,760,451
Trainable params: 1,760,451
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

However, when I tried to use fit_generator() method to train this model, I encounter InvalidArgumentError as following:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Input 'pred' passed float expected bool while building NodeDef 'decoder/terminal_GRU/PartitionedCall/cond/switch_pred/_1362' using Op<name=Switch; signature=data:T, pred:bool -> output_false:T, output_true:T; attr=T:type> [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_7791]
```

Is there anybody can tell me why this error occur? It is frustrating me I cannot find why this error occurs...

Comment: Can you maybe add your custom keras layer class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to change the variable name to inputs, because sometimes pred is used to define if the model is in prediction mode or training mode.

But it would really help if you showed us some of the code.

Good luck

Comment: actually, my custom layer consists of four part. custom_RNN(RNN), Terminal_GRU(custom_RNN), Terminal_GRUcell(Layer) and custom_rnn. I think the code seems too long... can you let me know what 'pred' really is?

Comment: Isn't it your function input variable? If not I'm afraid I can't help you

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. What do you mean function input and variable?

Comment: With a function input i mean ```def f(function_input):```

Answer (score 0):

The switch method receives 2 inputs : `pred` which is a boolean and a dead tensor. pred determines whether the data should pass through the `output_true` control branch or `output_false` control branch; the dead tensor is a way of letting tensorflow control the flow of the operations. The `pred` indicates whether operations in the `true_fn` or `false_fn` will be executed.If `pred` is set to false then the dead tensor is sent along the `true_fn` and vice versa. The output of the switch method produces atleast a data tensor and one or more dead tensors; the latter exists until a `tf.merge()` is called to absorb it. It is likely in this case that the `pred` is not correctly getting picked up; and this should happen if the operations preceeding `tf.cond()` call in the terminal_GPU layer is not providing proper sized tensors. If you have a custom condition function wrapped in tf for your layer, I would recommend providing a snippet. Also in the result you can see this:

`output_false:T, output_true:T; attr=T:type>`

this indicates that the `tf.cond()` is getting called.The error should be reproducible with model.fit as well since there seems like a logic error in the tf.cond(); without a snippet it is little difficult to answer the root cause; one temporary solution can be to add the layers by printing out the model summary one by one and replacing the `terminal_GRU` with keras GRU.Also `use_bias` in GRU can be set to True (not sure if it can resolve). For more samples on switch /merge:

- [Dead Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680462/tensorflow-node-which-is-dead)
- [Merge and Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107994/how-to-use-the-function-merge-and-switch-of-tensorflow)